# Formatting a Name out of image source

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to extract a name out of an image source file, here's the format of the string

```
source ='<img src="/ratefinder/images/providers/NAME-1307548896.gif">'
```

So I've tried using a slice(39..-1) and then a split('-') to get the name but I'm getting a nil class error. What would be the best way to go about extracting this?

EDIT: the slice

Comment: `slice(0..39)` won't get the `NAME-1307548896.gif` part... is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Yea I was trying to drop the first 39 constant characters, then split it and create a new string on the hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source.slice(0..39)` will get you this part:

```
<img src="/ratefinder/images/providers/N
```

I think you meant `source.slice(39..-1)`, or `source[39..-1]`:

```
"NAME-1307548896.gif">
```

Then `split` will work properly.

Comment: My mistake I made an edit above I did a, I'm still getting undefined method 'split' for nil:nilclass.

Comment: Thank you! I had not put the [0] after the split probably why I was getting the error. I'd up vote you if I could.

Answer (score 1):

use the following regex:

```
/.*\/(.*?)-.*$/
```

That is:

```
name = /.*\/(.*?)-.*$/.match(source)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be parsing html and file paths, you might want to use actual parser libraries instead of regexp.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pathname'

source = '<img src="/ratefinder/images/providers/NAME-1307548896.gif">'
src = Pathname.new Nokogiri::HTML(source).css('img').first.attributes['src'].value
filename = src.base_name.to_s  # => "NAME-1307548896.gif"
```